# Make a series with coefficients taken from a list of values

Tags: series-expansion

I want to create a function $u(x) = \sum_{j=0}^9 a_j \cos{j\pi x}$ where the $a_j$s come from a list of random numbers. I tried the following

```
Coeffs = RandomReal[1, 10]
u[x] := Series[(Part[Coeffs, j + 1]) Cos[π j x], {j, 0, 9}]
u[x]
```

and also

```
Coeffs = RandomReal[1, 10]
sum = 0
For[j = 0, j < 10, sum += Part[Coeffs, j + 1] Cos[j π x]]
u[x] = sum
u[x]
```

but none of these seem to work. The first one throws the error: `"The expression 1+k cannot be used as a part specification"`

while with the second one, the notebook doesnt finish running.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Table` is a good function to use for this application.  One way to use `Table` is with the `Dot` product function

```
coeffs = RandomReal[1, 10];
basis = Table[Cos[π j x], {j, 0, 9}];
sum = Dot[coeffs, basis]
```

If you don't need the varaibles `coeffs` or `basis` for anything else, you could do this

```
sum = Total @ Table[RandomReal[1] Cos[π j x], {j, 0, 9}]
```

These two approaches are quite common.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Thanks the advice

```
RandomReal[1, 10].Cos[Range[0, 9]*Pi*x]
```

**Original**

```
Coeffs = RandomReal[1, 10]
u[x_] = Coeffs.(Cos[#*Pi*x] & /@ Range[0, 9])
```

Comment: `Map` is not necessary because both `Times` and `Cos` are `Listable`.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]
f1[x_] := Inner[Times, RandomReal[1, 10], Cos[Range[0, 9] π x]]
f2[x_] := Dot[RandomReal[1, 10], Cos[π Range[0, 9] x]]

SeedRandom[1]
f1[x]
```

> ```
>  0.817389 + 0.11142 Cos[π x] + 0.789526 Cos[2 π x] + 
>  0.187803 Cos[3 π x] + 0.241361 Cos[4 π x] + 
>  0.0657388 Cos[5 π x] + 0.542247 Cos[6 π x] + 
>  0.231155 Cos[7 π x] + 0.396006 Cos[8 π x] + 
>  0.700474 Cos[9 π x]
> ```

```
SeedRandom[1]
f2[x]
```

> same result